# Android: I am trying to build custom List View that includes 3 items on each row

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to build custom List View that includes the following items on each row:

- clickable image
- text
- clickable image

I tried a lot of custom adapters that i found in other threads, but without any success until now. Both of the clickable images will use the text that is on that row.

Here is my row layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Minus"
        android:src="@drawable/minus" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="text" >

    </EditText>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Plus"
        android:src="@drawable/plus" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my list view:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewcart"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</ListView>
```

Here is my current custom adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private List<Item> items;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.shoppingcart_row, null);
        }

        Item p = items.get(position);

        if (p != null) {
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item);

            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText(p.getText());
            }
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

And here is how i try call it in my main class:

```
List test = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    test.add("test1");
    test.add("test2");
    test.add("test3");

    ListView cart = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewcart); 

    ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.shoppingcart_row, test);

    cart.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

I am getting an NPE. I printed the test list just in case, and it shows that there are the 3 elements that i am adding. I think the problem is somewhere in the custom adapter, but i cannot figure it out.

I also tried using ArrayList instead of List but i cannot modify my custom adapter to work with that. Can someone see what i did wrong in here? Thank you.

EDIT:

logcat error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.example.hrana.za.vkushti.ShoppingCart.additems(ShoppingCart.java:109)
   at com.example.hrana.za.vkushti.ShoppingCart.onCreate(ShoppingCart.java:49)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[test1, test2, test3]
```

EDIT 2

additems() method:

```
public void additems()
{       
    List test = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        test.add("test1");
        test.add("test2");
        test.add("test3");

        ListView cart = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewcart); 

        ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.shoppingcart_row, test);

        cart.setAdapter(customAdapter); // line 109
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: which line did you get a NPE?

Comment: I just added my logcat error in my question

Comment: Can you post the `additems` method and show which is line 109.

Comment: I just put another edit and include them in it

Comment: You do mean to have two `ListView`s?

Comment: No i need just one, but the program doesn't run properly if i remove either one of them ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line it gets the error on is basically saying it didn't find your `ListView`. This is because you may be confusing an ID for the `ListView`. In this error, *cart* is *null*.

Set your `Activity` to use the correct XML file.

```
setContentView(R.layout.shoppingcart);
```

Change this line

```
ListView cart = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewcart);
```

to

```
ListView cart = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Now change your XML for the layout with the `ListView` to this and delete the other `ListView`.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</ListView>
```

Now alter your custom adapter `ListAdapter` to use a `String` and not an `Item`. You'll get an invalid cast error when you instantiate the adapter.

Here is your adapter using an `ArrayList<String>` instead of `List<Item>`.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private ArrayList<String> items;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.shoppingcart_row, null);
        }

        String p = items.get(position);

        if (p != null) {
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item);

            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText(p.getText());
            }
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the name of the XML layout that has the `ListView`?

Comment: shoppingcart.xml  -  here is the ListView

Comment: I've updated by answer, but make sure your activity is using this XML file. `setContentView(R.layout.shoppingcart);`

Comment: In my code i used : setContentView(R.layout.shoppingcart_row);

Now i changed it as you suggested and i received an error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.content.ClipData$Item

Comment: Okay, you're getting somewhere now. `R.layout.shoppingcart_row` is incorrect because that is used inside your ListView, but `R.layout.shoppingcart` is used to actually display your `ListView`. You'll need to alter the custom adapter. I'll make an edit to my answer

Comment: Yuhuuuuuu!!! I combined your solution with one of Van Keizer and now it works!!! Thanks a lot guys

Comment: I've added the altered adapter, but sounds like you've fixed it. Make sure to upvote other helpful answers. Glad we could help.

Comment: I tried that, but i am not allowed yet... It requires 15 points of reputation, but thanks a lot to everybody!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

In your main class: `List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();`

in your adapter: `private List<String> items;`

Comment: ok, whats on line `ShoppingCart.java:109`? Also have you tryed `tt.setText(items.get(position).toString());`

Comment: Yes i tried that, it is not working.
Line 109 is cart.setAdapter(customAdapter);

Comment: Yuhuuuuuu!!! I combined your solution with one of Kirk  and now it works!!! Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you called setContentView(R.layout.layout) in your Activity before calling addItems();

Comment: I have that. In my case it is:
    setContentView(R.layout.shoppingcart_row);